# Web Server with HTTP::Daemon, HTML not rendering

Tags: perl

I figured out a way to create a quick web server in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -s -wl

use strict;

use HTTP::Daemon;
use HTTP::Headers;
use HTTP::Response;

sub help {
    print "$0 -port=<port-number>";
}

our $port;
our $addr = "localhost";

$port = 9000 unless defined $port;

my $server = HTTP::Daemon->new(
    LocalAddr => $addr,
    LocalPort => $port,
    Listen => 1,
    Reuse => 1,
);

die "$0: Could not setup server" unless $server;
print "$0: http://$addr:$port Accepting clients";

while (my $client = $server->accept()) {
    print "$0: Client received";

    $client->autoflush(1);

    my $request = $client->get_request;

    print "$0: Client's Request Received";
    print "$0: Request: " . $request->method;

    if ($request->method eq 'GET') {
        my $header = HTTP::Headers->new;
        $header->date( time );
        $header->server("$0");
        $header->content_type('text/html');

        my $content = "<!doctype html><html><head><title>Hello World</title></head><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>";
        my $response = HTTP::Response->new(200);
        $response->content($content);
        $response->header("Content-Type" => "text/html");

        $client->send_response($response);
    }

    print "$0: Closed";

    $client->close;
    undef($client);
}
```

But for some reason, every time I access `localhost:9000` it displays part of the HTTP Header - date, server, content-length and content-type - and the content. It doesn't render it as an HTML page. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the `-l` switch:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -s -wl
                         ^
```

It sets the output record separator to the value of the input record separator (a newline), which results in additional newlines being added to HTTP server output, and a broken HTTP response.